# Timestamp on row edit by importrange

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found a script that inputs a timestamp into a cell which is working fine when I edit cells in a row by direct input to cell but when the cell with importrange result changes it doesn't work.

Is there any chance to make it work and input a timestamp when cell with importrange changes it value as well?

this is the code I have

```
    function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1"]; 

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (!sheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || range.columnStart == 1) return;
  sheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 8, range.rowEnd - range.rowStart + 1).setValue(new Date());
}
```

Comment: I think that in the current stage, unfortunately, the OnEdit trigger cannot directly detect the change of cell imported by `importrange`. In your situation, I think that it is required to use a workaround. But, about `Is there any chance to make it work and input a timestamp when cell with importrange changes it value as well?`, I think that more information will help users think of a solution. In your situation, how is the sheet and range of `importrange` edited?

Comment: so I have one spreadsheet which works as a database and the other one that is importing from it. It is basically date of shipment so I want to have a timestamp when that date is changed

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `so I have one spreadsheet which works as a database and the other one that is importing from it. It is basically date of shipment so I want to have a timestamp when that date is changed`, I couldn't understand the method for editing the sheet and range of `importrange`.

Comment: so in database I have order number and the shipment date (dates are being updated everyday). In the spreadsheet that is importing those data I would like to have a timestamp when date in database will change. I want to see when and which order has changed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. About `when date in database will change`, can I ask you about the details of the method for changing it? I think that in your situation, it is required to detect the change of the sheet and range of `importrange`.

Comment: regular input by hand 手入力になります。

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `regular input by hand 手入力になります。`, in this case, I think that the edit of the sheet and range of `importrange` can be detected by the installable OnEdit trigger. But, I cannot know your actual Spreadsheet. So, as one more question, can you provide the sample Spreadsheets for correctly replicating your current situation? From the sample, I would like to try to prepare a sample script.

Answer (score 0):

onEdit runs only when a user changes a value on the spreadsheet.  Changes in cell value resulting from another script or changes resulting from a formula calculation do not trigger this function.

See [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) here.